# How to make a function from body with variable number of arguments?

Tags: functions, function-construction

Suppose I have an UNKNOWN function, which generates formulas with given number of `x[i]`.

```
In[132]:= p[n_Integer] := (* some expression*) ;
p[10]

Out[]= (* some expression, containing x[1], x[2], ... , x[10] *)
```

Now, how can I regard generated output as a body for a `Function` with variable number of arguments and create that function?

In other words, I would like to write a function

```
In[163]:= pf[xs___] := Block[{n, rep, x},
   n = Length[{xs}];
   rep = Flatten[Table[{x[i - 1] -> {xs}[[i]]}, {i, 1, n}]];
   p[n - 1] /. rep
   ];


pf[p]
Out[]= (*an expression where x[1] replaced for p*)

pf[p, q]
Out[]= (*an expression where x[1] replaced for p and x[2] replaced for q *)
```

but shorter.

Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

There is a function named `Function`, which does NEARLY what I need, but for constant expressions. May be it is possible to "unhold" it's arguments somehow, or somehow change evaluation order?

**UPDATE 2**

Required expression should contain `p[]` call, otherwise it is not a problem. The problem is that body of resulting function is generated by another function `p[]`.

Comment: Regarding the update, I doubt using `Function[{...}, ...]` can make your code *shorter*.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the `ReplaceAll` approach, you can do it with `Block` and `Set`:

```
Clear[f]
f[n_Integer] := {x[0], Array[x, n]}

Clear[fp]
fp[var__] :=
    Block[{x},
          MapIndexed[Set[x[#2[[1]] - 1], #1] &, {var}];
          f[Length@{var} - 1]
         ]

f[3]
fp[a, c, 3, w]
```

> ```
> {x[0], {x[1], x[2], x[3]}}
>
> {a, {c, 3, w}}
> ```

In case you even don't like `Length`:

```
Clear[fp2]
fp2[var__] :=
    Block[{x},
          MapIndexed[(Set[x[#2[[1]] - 1], #1]; #2[[1]] - 1) &, {var}][[-1]] // f
         ]

fp2[a, c, 3, w]
```

> ```
> {a, {c, 3, w}}
> ```